# How to retrieve Virtual Disk Images per VirtualGuest?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to retrieve Virtual Disk Image list per my virtual Guests.

Looking through API DOC, there is a method to retrieve Virtual Disk Images list per customer. but it does not tell me which virtual guests is actually owning the virtual disk.

I guess I should use Object Filter but i am still not understanding how to use to retrieve what i want, can someone give me an example of cURL for this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve what you require, it is necessary to use Object Masks beside Object Filters, please try the following curl request by using **SoftLayer_Account::getVirtualDiskImages** method:

Using Object Masks will display the IDs of the attached server or VSI along with other specified properties we defined:

```
curl -g "https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualDiskImages?objectMask=mask[capacity,createDate,description,id,name,units,blockDevices[guestId]]"
```

Now by using objectFilter along with the Mask you may narrow the returned list of disk images by using the id of the device (Virtual Guest in this case) where they are associated.

```
curl -g "https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualDiskImages?objectMask=mask[capacity,createDate,description,id,name,units,blockDevices[guestId]]&objectFilter=%7B%22virtualDiskImages%22%3A%7B%22blockDevices%22%3A%7B%22guestId%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A[deviceId]%7D%7D%7D%7D"
```

Do not forget to change the "**[username]**" and "**[apiKey]**" for valid credentials, and the "**[deviceId]**" for your (Virtual) ***guestId***.

Another method to retrieve similar information directly by **guestId** (VSI id) and without using object mask and filters is [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getBlockDevices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getBlockDevices).

For more information I recommend to see below:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-1

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks